# Backup Exec Command Line (BEMCLI) - outputting Agent Server string

Tags: powershell, report

I am writing a report for a customer and one of the variables I have written is:

```
$Table8 = Get-BEJob |
          Where-Object {($_.JobType -eq "Backup") -and ($_.Status -eq "Scheduled")} |
          Get-BEJobHistory |
          Where-Object {$_.EndTime -gt (Get-date).AddDays(-1)} |
          sort EndTime -Descending
```

But when I call the script later using:

```
$Table8 | Select Name, JobStatus, AgentServer, StartTime, EndTime
```

All the data outputs apart from AGENTSERVER which reads:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BackupExec.Management.CLI.BEAgentServer]
```

When I run the command in the shell, I get the data in brackets (`{}`), for example `{Server1} {Server2}`. I am not really sure what the `{}` means in this context. I guess the data isn't going into the pipeline to output.

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Example of the report output below:

[image: Report Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're getting means that the `AgentServer` property holds a list of elements, not just a single element. You can get the server in the desired format by selecting the first element of the list

```
... | Select-Object Name, JobStatus, @{n='AgentServer';e={$_.AgentServer[0]}}, StartTime, EndTime
```

or by joining the list elements with a delimiter

```
... | Select-Object Name, JobStatus, @{n='AgentServer';e={$_.AgentServer -join ','}}, StartTime, EndTime
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  @{n='AgentServer';e={$_.AgentServer -join ','}} allow the large list of servers to be displayed sequentially in a list. Is it possible to get each element on a new line?

Comment: `-join ','` -> ``-join "`n"``